# Route array of path options matters with params?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a root provider in my app which checks for `id` value in the URL, such as on an URL page refresh and the global store is not updated, we need to set the value of associated details based on this ID.

Using the hook is very straight forward:

```
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
```

However, the id is `undefined` unless I have a list of all the possible routes with params, so I need to wrap everything with a Route component, using an array of paths like: `<Route path={[..array of routes]}>`.

However, it seems the order of the array paths matter.  Why is this?

Works:

```
<Route path={["/nested/again/:id", "/nested/:id", "/:id", "/"]}>
```

Does not work:

```
<Route path={[ "/", "/:id", "/nested/:id", "/nested/again/:id"]}>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/useparams-with-array-of-route-match-options-forked-3dcbz?file=/example.js

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7726#issuecomment-750755953

The expected behavior of the array of paths is:

> This is expected behavior that matches Switch. It goes through the list of paths in order and matches whichever is first. If you remove the "/" path, you'll find it matches on the "/:id" path first and returns "nested" for the param. The same happens with Switch: